# According to the Rishonim who hold a Bracha Levatala is forbidden Min Hatorah, why do we need a category of Safek Brachot Lehakel?

Tags: blessing, safek, bracha-levatala

If a Bracha Levatala (blessing in vain) is forbidden from Torah Law, why do we need a special category of Safek Brachot Lehakel?

Almost all Brachot are Derabanan, and how could we do a safek mitzvah derabanan and be over (violate) an issur deorayta (from the Torah)?

(To make the question easier we can ignore Brachot which are deorayta).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/113918/1739

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we have an explicit rule of Safek Brachos Lehakel if we already have a greater encompassing rule of Safek D'Rabanan L'kulah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/113918/why-do-we-have-an-explicit-rule-of-safek-brachos-lehakel-if-we-already-have-a-gr)

Comment: not really, but it is a good start to my question. My question is only going according to a minority of the Rishonim who hold Bracha Levatala is a deorayta. How could you ever violate a deorayta to be mekayem a derabanan? (I understand if it's only derabanan, then the Rabbis could tell you just to violate it, even in a place of safek).

Comment: You define Levatala as 'in vain', which I assume means for no purpose or benefit. If one is doing something Misafek, it is no longer for no purpose, it is for the purpose of solving the state of 'Safek' that one is in. Maybe that wouldn't fall under the category of 'in vain'.

Comment: very interesting. Definitely a chiddush but I really like it!

Comment: @talmidforlife where do you see that safek berachos is a separate category? do you know that those rishonim who hold bracha levatala is doraisa don't just subsume safek brachos into the already existing general rule of safek doraisa?

Comment: i think it is the Rambam who holds brachos levatala is doraisa, though some mefarshim interpret the Rambam differently. well, since he holds safek doraisa l'chumra is only a law m'drabanan. oh, i thought that would answer your question. but i don't think it does.

Comment: It would answer the question, if all Rishonim who held Bracha Levatala is deoraysa also held that Safek Deoraysa Lechumra is only a Derabanan.  That would mean the second time I would make the Bracha, it would only be a safek deoraysa, a derabanan. So one derabanan can beat another one. But then we have the special rule of safek brachos lehakel.  Very nice.

Comment: According to Rishonim who hold that it's deoraysa, then the gemara should have said that it's a safek deoraysa, not that it's safek brachos lehakel. This clearly has to be a new category according to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before suggesting some actual answers to the question, I will point out two contrasting opinions that essentially strengthen the question, by answering (in one form or another) *ein hachi nami*:

Rabbeinu Manoach (quoted in [Beit Yosef Orach Chaim 67](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.67.1?lang=he)) says that the reason we don't repeat *berachot miderabannan* (i.e. why we apply *safek berachot lehakel*) is because of the need to be stringent on *lo tisa*.

In contrast, [Peri Chadash Orach Chaim 67](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x549) writes, based on this question, that it must be that *beracha levatala* in only forbidden *miderabannan*, as otherwise we wouldn't need to have a rule of *safek berachot lehakel*.

If we want to accept (unlike Peri Chadash) that *beracha levatala* is forbidden *mideoraita*, but also want to undertand (unlike Rabbeinu Manoach) that *safek berachot lehakel* is not simply a corollary of the need to be stringent on *lo tisa*, then [Penei Yehoshua to Berachot 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Penei_Yehoshua_on_Berakhot.12a.4?lang=he) has a couple of points which are relevant:

> דלא מקרי נמי ברכה לבטלה כיון שרוצה להסתלק מן הספק ואשכחן טובא שחכמים עצמן תקנו כמה ברכות על הספק ולא הוי ברכה לבטלה:‏
>
> [Repeating a *beracha* out of doubt] is not called a 'blessing in vain' as he wants to remove himself from a status of doubt. We find many times that the Sages themselves enacted to say blessings out of doubt and it is not a blessing in vain.

While he does not say this explicitly with reference to those that hold that *beracha levatala* is a problem *mideoraita*, my sense from the piece is that he thinks that this reason applies equally well according to that understanding, and, I think that logically this should be true.

Alternatively, he later suggests:

> דהא לכ"ע יכול לברך בלא הזכרת שם אלא בלשון תרגום ובכה"ג לא שייך איסורא דלא תשא ואפ"ה יצא שפיר ידי ברכה
>
> According to everyone [in a case of doubt] he could make the blessing, but only mention G-d's Name in translation. [Reciting a blessing] in such a manner involves no prohibition of reciting G-d's Name in vain, but he does nevertheless fulfill his obligation to make a blessing.

To summarize, two possible approaches as to why we still need the principle of *safek berachot lehakel* if *beracha levatala* is forbidden *mideoraita*:

1. Repeating a *beracha* out of doubt is not classified as a *beracha levatala* / mentioning G-d's Name in vain.
2. If one did have to repeat a *beracha* out of doubt, one could do so utilizing a translation of G-d's Name, and thus not say G-d's Name in vain.